# Custom Redirection based on Geolocation for multiple countries in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, geolocation, conditional-statements

Based on *"[Custom Redirection based on Geolocation for specific products in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57466134/custom-redirection-based-on-geolocation-for-specific-products-in-woocommerce/57467575#57467575)"* answer to my previous question, I should need the country condition to be an array of values instead.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To handle multiple countries** you must replace in the condition:

```
WC_Geolocation::geolocate_ip()['country'] === 'GE'
```

by:

```
in_array( WC_Geolocation::geolocate_ip()['country'], array( 'GE', 'UK', 'FR' ) )
```

where `array( 'GE', 'UK', 'FR' )` is the array of country codes.